# Laravel Yajra Datatables, multi level relationship on column name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatable, relationship, query-builder

Javascript: {data:'category_name',name:'sale.sale_detail.product.category.category_name'}
is it possible to access multi level relationship?

sale table has a sub table"sale_detail" and sale_detail contains product_id and also product table has id of category table

Comment: You should try formatting the data server-side. If you're using laravel, just use DB::table function with multiple joins and then pass it to DataTables function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify title of question, include [example] of your code, . See [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give you an example from my code. You can use `join` as mentioned by @Japheth Suarez:

```
$category = Category::findOrFail($slug);

$reviews = DB::table('reviews')
                    ->join('users', 'reviews.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->select('reviews.*', DB::raw('CONCAT(users.first_name, "  ", users.last_name) AS full_name'))
                    ->where('category_id', '=', $category->id);
```

Let me say to you that I have tried `Eager Loading` with DataTables but never worked very good in terms of performance. So the best solution for me was to use `join` instead of using it this way `$posts = Post::with('user')->select('posts.*');`.

Hope that this helps.
Happy coding!